# Gershgorin theorem and strictly diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, gershgorin-sets

A is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix. Prove $ \prod_{i=1}^n (|a_{ii}|-\sum_{j \ne i}|a_{ij}|)\leq |det(A)|$.

ps: I tried Gershgorin theorem, but I cannot prove eigenvalues are contained in different Gershgorin circles. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: See also https://planetmath.org/ProofOfDeterminantLowerBoundOfAStrictDiagonallyDominantMatrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*simple case*
the underlying idea is right-- solve a simple case first -- where all Gerschgorin discs are disjoint. In this simple case we have
$0\lt \big\vert a_{i,i}\big\vert - \sum_{j\neq i}\big \vert a_{i,j}\big\vert=\Big\vert \big\vert a_{i,i}\big\vert - \sum_{j\neq i}\big \vert a_{i,j}\big\vert \Big\vert \leq \big \vert\lambda_i\big \vert$
by Gersochgorin's Discs, and mutliplying over the bound gives the result.

The key insight is that **left multiplication by an invertible diagonal matrix does not change strict diagonal dominance**, and we can use this to get the general case from the simple case.

*general case*
consider $B:= DA$
for some well chosen diagonal matrix $D$ with non-zero elements on its diagonal.  As we'll see $B$ is the above simple case. To make this easy, go in two steps, $D=D^{(2)}D^{(1)}$ where $D^{(1)}$ is the 'homogenization matrix' and $D^{(2)}$ is the 'qualitative matrix'.

1.) Select $D^{(1)}$ such that $(D^{(1)}A)$ has each diagonal element $= 1$.

2.) $D^{(2)}$ has each diagonal element positive and is selected as follows:

Consider
$D^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1 &\mathbf {0}^T\\ \mathbf 0 &I_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$
and observe that for large enough $\sigma_1$, the Gerschgorin disc associated with row one of $(D^{(2)}D^{(1)}A)$ is necessarily disjoint from the discs of rows $\geq 2$. So select (and fix) some satisfactory $\sigma_1$.

Now consider
$D^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1 &0&\mathbf {0}^T\\ 0&\sigma_2&\mathbf 0^T\\ \mathbf 0& \mathbf 0 &I_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$.
And observe that for large enough $\sigma_2$, the Gerschgorin discs associated with the first two rows of $(D^{(2)}D^{(1)}A)$ are necessarily disjoint from each other and from those of rows $\geq 3$.  This process continues n-3 more times and we have

$B=DA = D^{(2)}D^{(1)}A $
where all Gerschgorin discs of $B$ are disjoint.  Of course by the simple argument:

$\prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\vert b_{i,i}\vert - \sum_{j\neq i}\big \vert b_{i,j}\big\vert\Big)\leq \big \vert \det\big(B\big)\big \vert $
now rescale each side by the positive number given by $\vert\det\big(D^{-1}\big)\big \vert=\Big\vert \prod_{i=1}^n d_{i,i}\Big\vert^{-1}$  and you recover

$\prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\big\vert a_{i,i}\big\vert - \sum_{j\neq i}\big \vert a_{i,j}\big\vert\Big)$
$=\prod_{i=1}^n\Big( \vert d_{i,i}^{-1}\vert b_{i,i} - \vert d_{i,i}^{-1}\vert \cdot \sum_{j\neq i}\big \vert b_{i,j}\big\vert\Big)$
$=\Big\vert \prod_{i=1}^n d_{i,i}\Big\vert^{-1}\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n\Big(\vert b_{i,i}\vert - \sum_{j\neq i}\big \vert b_{i,j}\big\vert\Big)$
$\leq \Big\vert \prod_{i=1}^n d_{i,i}\Big\vert^{-1} \cdot\Big \vert \det\big(B\big)\Big \vert$
$= \Big \vert \det\big(D^{-1}\big)\Big\vert \cdot \Big \vert \det\big(B\big)\Big\vert$
$= \Big \vert \det\big(D^{-1}B\big)\Big \vert$
$ =\Big \vert \det\big(A\big)\Big \vert $

Comment: Very well done. +1. In short, if $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n)$ is any positive diagonal matrix such that $\frac{d_i}{d_{i+1}}$ is sufficiently large, then $B=DA$ is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix with $n$ disjoint Gerschgorin discs. Therefore $\prod_i\left(|b_{ii}|-\sum_{j\ne i}|b_{ij}|\right)\le\det(B)$ and in turn $\prod_i\left(|a_{ii}|-\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\right)\le\det(A)$.